# HTML mailto Yahoo Mail with recipient name

Tags: html, mailto, yahoo-mail

I would like to add the names of the recipients in a html mailto link for Yahoo Mail users. I know that they can set Yahoo Mail as a default handler or mailto: links, but I have a particular use case where solving this could be helpful.

Currently, I already have a compose link that works:

`https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=john@doe.com`

In particular I would like to be able format `?to=john@doe.com` so that Yahoo is consistent with what Gmail (and more) which can include the recipients name using this markup:

`?to="John Doe"<john@doe.com>"`.

Unfortunately, I can't find what markup Yahoo Mail requires, or if it can be done at all through Yahoo Mail.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to set this up on your end only or for a web page in general? As far as I'm aware, you can't change the mailto functionality for others, it just pulls the default mail program that has been set on the client's computer. If you want to change it for yourself however, that's definitely doable.

Comment: This is for a webpage that I have, I am trying to build a select box for send off emails from different providers. I use the Craigslist reply function as inspiration, but because I know the recipients email address I would like to get the recipients name in there, but I can't figure out the markup to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo does not allow you to mark up the name of the recipient through the URL like Gmail and Outlook, you can only place email addresses in the `to`, `cc`, or `bcc` fields.

Answer (score 0):

23-12-2021: Surprisingly now it works! I am making a laravel app and what I wanted was what the author of this question was asking about. So I gave it a try and it worked.

Sample html code:

```
<a href="https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to={{ $supplier->email }}" target="_blank">{{ $supplier->email }}</a>
```